# Does ImageResizer support delivering fallback image when image corrupted?

Tags: imageresizer

We use ImageResizer images in a number of places, for example embedded images into pdf Reports, and sometimes users will upload corrupted files or pdf's with passwords. These currently thrown an exception and don't return any image.

Does ImageResizer have some way of returning an alternative fallback image instead? (Ideally with equivalent scaling, and returned immediately, without any 301/302 redirect). In a perfect world we could specify rules for mapping exceptions types to an appropriate fallback image.

We have no control client-side to handle this (e.g. in Telerik/Microsot reporting embedded images)

Answer (score 0):

We currently only do this for 404. Masking 500 errors could be even more problematic.

You could copy/modify this plugin, though: https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/image404